# Is the tap water clean in Manila?

Tags: health, philippines, tap-water, manila

It seems like a silly question for most of my travels, as I'll be in a hotel, but I will travel a little bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on who you ask, basically.

The [latest report I can find](http://internationalwateranalysis.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/water-in-manila-safe-to-drink-for-now/) states that it's "safe to drink - for now".

The water quality is managed by The Manila Water Company, and they do monthly checks of over 1000 samples.

However, it's also worth noting the article points out that during rainy season, the risk of contamination is higher from pipes being submerged in floodwaters.

However, that's the "official" report.  The article goes on to say:

> Officials often claim that water is safe to drink in Manila but
>   **foreigners are advised not to drink tap water**, even those served in fine restaurants. Restaurants may also say that their water is
>   boiled and/or filtered but they often use tap water. **Travel agencies
>   and other officials advise that visitors in the Philippines only take
>   mineral or bottled water** that is sealed when unopened.

Comment: Beat me to the answer, yeah -- don't drink tap water. Your hotel will provide bottled water as will most restaurants. Ice is invariably bought in and made from filtered water. But there's no need to be really strict about it, like avoiding things washed with tap water (I brush my teeth with tap water here) just best to minimize the amount you take. Also, in general it tastes pretty weird, bottled water is cheap and ubiquitous. Or just drink beer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

MY wife and I got ,stomach cramps and bloating after drinking water and or ice,
The last few days only drank soft drink or bottled water, big improvement, Don't drink the water

Answer (score 0):

I'm a foreigner living in Manila and I've been drinking tap water for 8 years. I haven't experienced any problems.

Comment: As someone living there your system is used to the water, tourists may experience more problems.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't drink tap water in the Philippines. I can only drink tap water that was boiled or filtered. If you drink tap water, you can definitely taste chlorine.

Comment: Chlorine is added to make it safe to drink, avoiding that is a preference, not a need. So I guess your answer contradicts itself.

Comment: @Willeke Chlorine helps kill bacteria, but it can't do anything for heavy metal contaminants etc.

Comment: I did not imply it makes bad water safe but it being there is no reason not to drink otherwise safe water.

Comment: Be aware that while chlorine kills germs, too much can't be good for you. If your tap water tastes like a swimming pool water, there's probably an excess of chlorine. Normal tap water shouldn't have any smell or noticeable taste after disinfection. https://www.homewater.com/blog/chlorination-in-city-water-important-information